Why a change in input type=checkbox doesn't cause a change event?
I have an hierarchy-like structure of <input type='checkbox'>. I add an eventListener for every checkbox of each level of the hierarchy (except for the last level checkboxes) iteratively on a creating checkbox:
function createCheckbox(id) {
    const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.value = id;
    checkbox.id = id;
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function (x) {
        const activeCheckbox = x.target;
        const flag = activeCheckbox.checked;
        const descendants = activeCheckbox.closest("li").querySelectorAll(`input[type=checkbox]`);
        descendants.forEach(d => d.checked = flag);
...
}

The last level checkboxes are created via another function like this:
function createFinalCheckbox(id) {
    const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.value = id;
    checkbox.id = id;
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function (x) {
        // some code
...
}

The issue I am facing is that even if the last checkbox becomes checked through the function of the upper-level checkbox (descendants.forEach(d => d.checked = flag)), it doesn't run my code which is supposed (as I expect) to run on a change event.

change events are only triggered automatically when inputs are changed by the user, not by code.

@Barmar Can I trigger them somehow by the code?

Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Welcome to StackOverflow. For a full context, please provide a minimal reproducible example

you can also use only one event delegation on input event for both form's elements...

@MisterJojo fair enough! Thank you. Worked perfectly
